# c# click a div element in webbrowser

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

I'm trying to get my c# code to click a div element on a website. The code for the div is:

```
<div class="div5" onclick="sendpost(8);" style="cursor: pointer; background-color: rgb(64, 64, 64);">
```

This is what I've tried so far without any success:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div").GetElementsByClass("div5")[0].InvokeMember("click");
```

Another problem with the code above: it won't know what element to click, as there multiple matching elements on the page. The only difference is `onclick="sendpost(8);"` (but there is a `sendpost(7);` in another div element with class div5).

Comment: On the div tag, start by adding an ID and runat="server" for c# to acknowledge it. If that doesnt do it, you might have to make the div tag use JavaScript to click() a c# button on the page.

Comment: are you using MVC or WebForms ?

Comment: @stralos i am using WebForms

Comment: This may be a stupid suggestion, but have you tried `ebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div").GetElementsByClass("div5")[0].click();`. Just like in javascript